# Mongo query to filter today data when date & time is in string in different keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I write a mongo query to  filter today's record with time when I have date and time in string in json object in mongo.

My Json Object is

```
{
  "_id": ""
  "data_id": 3227,
  "series_id": 240,
  "date_wise": "17 Sep 2023, Sunday",
  "match_date": "17-Sep",
  "match_time": "01:30 PM",
}
```

I need to find out if the following date is $lt the current date/time by comparing the match_date and match_time key in the json object.

I have wrote query but its not working because I believe the json object date and time  is in string.

```
db.posts.find({match_date: {$lt: new Date()},match_time: {$lt: new Date()}});
```

Any suggestions of great help!!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `$dateFromString` with a `$expr`:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {$lte: [
      {$dateFromString: {dateString: {$concat: ["$date_wise", " ", "$match_time"]}}},
      "$$NOW"
    ]}
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DLvXMcC5wk3)

But a better option is to add an ISODate to your document, which can be done like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{$set: {date: {$dateFromString: {
          dateString: {$concat: ["$date_wise", " ", "$match_time"]}
  }}}}],
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8PD7z3PKoVL)

Comment: This answer is superior to the accepted answer in multiple ways: 1. provided short and concise solution for OP's scenario 2. long-term mitigation for date object type 3. playground to demonstrate as usual 4. likely human-written :)